# How to know if CSV downloaded?

Tags: javascript, csv, tableau-api

We developed a front end on top of Tableau using Javascript and Tableau API. We have a feature where a user can export to csv. We accomplish this by inserting the location of the sheet into hidden iframe as below

```
document.getElementById('iFrameExcel').src = "https://server/t/project/views/view1/sheet.csv
```

I want to create some sort of a message when the download has completed but the problem is I can't find a way to know if the download has completed or not. Is there an event that Tableau api fires when the download is completed?

Answer (score -1):

If you are loading the CSV into a new frame the frame load event will fire when it is loaded.

```
$("#iFrameExcel").load( function() {
     //this fires when the frame loads
});
```

This implies that the content-disposition of the excel document is coming in as inline and the user's browser can load it though.  Are you sure your user can load excel inline?

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/3574/

Am I getting downvoted because I used jquery?